# Callback when a child_process has successfully processed a signal

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I need to verify that a `child_process` has successfully been killed because I cannot execute the next action if that process is still alive.

```
var proc = require('child_process');

var prog = proc.spawn('myprog', ['--option', 'value']);
prog.on('data', function(data) {
  // Do something
});
```

Somewhere else in the code I reach to a certain event and on a certain condition I need to kill `prog`:

```
prog.kill('SUGHUP');
// Only when the process has successfully been killed execute next
// Code...
```

Since `kill` is probably async, I am using `q`. I would like to use `q` on `kill` but `kill` does not have a callback which is executed when the signal has successfully been processed.

How to do?

### Possible idea

If I send a message to process `prog` and in process `prog` when receiving the message I kill it? How can tell a process to self-kill?

Comment: Waiting for the signal to be caught and processed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't prog.exec() with the option killsignal and a callback fit your needs ?